# What is the worst case Big-Oh using list.retainAll

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, big-o

```
static List<String> common(String[] A, String[] B){
    Collection<String> listone = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(A));
    List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(B));
    sorted.retainAll( listone );
return sorted;
}
```

I have tried looking for the API source code; but I could not find anything for the list.retainAll method.

However i do believe that it is O(n). Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

The answer depends on the type of collections passed in as the parameter to `retainAll`. Here is an implementation from [Open JDK](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
public boolean retainAll(Collection<?> c) {
    boolean modified = false;
    Iterator<E> e = iterator();
    while (e.hasNext()) {
       if (!c.contains(e.next())) {
           e.remove();
           modified = true;
       }
   }
   return modified;
}
```

Here is the timing for the case when removal is O(1):

- If `c.contains(v)` finishes in O(1), then `retainAll` is O(N).
- If `contains` is O(Log M), then `retainAll` is O(N*Log M).
- If `contains` is O(M), then `retainAll` is O(N*M).

If you are planning to call `retainAll` with a large collection, and performance is critical, you may be better off constructing a `HashSet` for the list being retained. The speedup may be significant.

```
Set<String> temp = new HashSet<String>(b);
a.retainAll(temp);
```

**Note:** `ArrayList<T>` [has its own implementation of `retainAll`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29), which does not remove the individual elements as it goes, rewriting elements that it wants to keep into the initial portion of the list, and then drops the "tail" elements all at once in O(1). Combined with the `HashSet<T>` from above, this would provide you with an algorithm that is O(M+N) in time and O(M) in space.

Comment: `e.remove()` for an `ArrayList` is also linear.  I think it depends on both the type of the "retainee" as well as the specified collection.  Best case would be linear with eg a `LinkedList` retainee and a specified `HashSet`.

Comment: @msandiford Thanks for a nice comment! I added more info to explain this.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: `ArrayList` has its own non-default `retainAll` implementation that runs in O(NM).  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.retainAll%28java.util.Collection%29

Comment: @LouisWasserman Ah, you're right, that's the algorithm that already does what I suggested the OP should do.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that worst case would be `O(size A * size B)` or `O(nm)`. This is due to retain all looking at each item in `sorted` and comparing it against each item in `listone` (using iterators).

At worst, if no items are similar, then this would happen. However, if all of the items in `sorted` are towards the end of the iterator for `listone`, then this would also 'nearly' happen.